# How to fix build error while using Lerna MonoRepo pattern on Android (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, lerna, monorepo

While using Lerna MonoRepo I'm getting build error on Android, while there is no errors on iOS (XCode 10.2.1, Lerna 3.15.0, React-Native 0.59.9)

I re-arranged the path of `node_modules` (took it outside, into the main project folder) according to Lerna pattern because of the MonoRepo requirements. Now the new path for `node_modules` is:

`../Documents/ProjectFolder/node_modules`

But when I try to build with `yarn react-native run-android`, it looks for `node_modules` in:

`../Documents/ProjectFolder/SampleProject/node_modules`

How can I change or configure the path for `node_modlues`for Gradle?

Note: `yarn react-native run-ios` works fine, builds without errors.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/MyUser/Documents/ProjectFolder/packages/SampleProject/android/app/build.gradle' line: 79

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not read script '/Users/MyUser/Documents/ProjectFolder/packages/SampleProject/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' as it does not exist.
```